# Android: BaseAdapter redraws the same data

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I've created a custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter and am trying to display a scrollable list view that expands whenever the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom. However, when updating the underlying ArrayList, instead of generating new views for the new elements and appending them to the bottom of the list view, some already existing elements in the ArrayList are being redrawn.

I am downloading JSON data from a Wordpress Blog and want to display the image and excerpt of each post in a list view. I implemented a listener in the list view that is called whenever the user scrolled to the bottom. When scrolled to the bottom, the downloading of the next three most recent blog posts is executed. When the downloading is finished, I update the ArrayList of BlogPosts `blogPosts` as seen below and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
I have checked that the JSON Data is downloaded correctly: The first three most recent posts are shown when I switch to the archive view (see video). When the downloading is finished, `addToPosts()` is called. The parameter `posts` is also correct and consists of the next three posts.

*list_view.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/archive_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_panel_archive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

*list_view_item.xml*

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*CustomAdapter.java*

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<BlogPost> blogPosts;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BlogPost> blogPosts) {
        this.blogPosts = blogPosts;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return blogPosts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return blogPosts.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, 
                viewGroup,  false);
            holder.tvname = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_lv);
            holder.iv = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_lv);

            final BlogPost currentPost = (BlogPost) getItem(i);
            holder.tvname.setText(currentPost.getContent());

            if (!currentPost.isAsyncTaskFinished()){
                currentPost.setListener(new BlogPost.ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange() {
                        holder.iv.setImageBitmap(currentPost.getBitmap());
                    }
                });
            }else{
                holder.iv.setImageBitmap(currentPost.getBitmap());
            }

        }
        return view;
    }


public void addToPosts(ArrayList<BlogPost> posts){
    this.blogPosts.addAll(posts);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView tvname;
    private ImageView iv;
    }
}
```

*Setup of list view & custom adapter:*

```
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
firstThreePosts);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

ProgressBar bar = findViewById(R.id.loading_panel_archive);
bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//scroll listener...
```

I expected that the next three posts are appended to the list view,
however this is what happened:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AuPD10kPw_c5ghHaajc4OYFvkV1K?e=iVc2mS

The sixth and fifth post are drawn over and over again and the new posts
are never drawn.
Maybe the parameter `i` in `getView` causes this behaviour, but I can't really understand what's happening.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup,  false);
        holder.tvname = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_lv);
        holder.iv = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_lv);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    final BlogPost currentPost = (BlogPost) getItem(i);
    holder.tvname.setText(currentPost.getContent());

    if (!currentPost.isAsyncTaskFinished()){
        currentPost.setListener(new BlogPost.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                holder.iv.setImageBitmap(currentPost.getBitmap());
            }
        });
    }else{
        holder.iv.setImageBitmap(currentPost.getBitmap());
    }

    return view;
}
```

Hope that helps!